# Module Background Image (bg_image) installed, image not showing

Tags: theming

Installed the [Background Images](https://drupal.org/project/bg_image) module with path of image, but nothing is showing.  I am using 'node/*' to apply image to all pages

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When they say "You need to specify a css selector..." that is an existing selector; the module is not creating a new selector. Say, if you are giving the image to #Container, that is the selector you are asked for. See https://drupal.org/node/2043709 might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the base bg_image settings? You need to specify a css selector to apply the background image to.

Comment: Can you expand this answer a bit?  Thanks.

Comment: In Configuration>Background Image, I assign say "qwert" to CSS selector and horizontal (=center) vertical (=top). What else do I need to make the image show up? Should I make it .qwert or #qwert for selector format? Do I need to write something for "qwert" in the stylesheet? Thanks.